# NSURLRequest http protocol version

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlrequest

It is quite a simple question from me today. Is it possible to set specific HTTP protocol version to `NSURLRequest` object (1.0 or 1.1, for example)?

An example of what I'm talking about on telnet:

```
pavlov:~ pavlov$ telnet ya.ru 80
Trying 87.250.250.3...
Connected to ya.ru.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /index.php HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: Good question, I see that you can set header values us NSMutableURLRequest but version isn't a header.  There's also a method propertyForKey:inRequest: that might give you the version option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the HTTP version of a `NSURLRequest`. However you can use the `CFNetwork` framework. It's the C framework on top of which `NSURLConnection` is based.

The `CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest` function creates a new message with an arbitrary HTTP protocol version. Then, that message may be used to create an input stream using the `CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest` function.

Documentation: [CFNetwork - Communicating with HTTP Servers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFHTTPTasks/CFHTTPTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH5-SW2)

Comment: As i'm understand - default requested HTTP protocol version by NSURLRequest is 1.1?

Comment: Yes, it defaults to `HTTP/1.1`